# Select records from sql server step by step i.e 500, 500

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, telerik

There is a table of account in database it contain 50000 records.

i am showing the record on telerik grid, currently i fetch all 50000 records and display it but it is working slow, so here i want to select records step by step i.e select first 500 and display it on grid and than again fetch next 500 and attached it to grid.

How can i get this implemented using asp.net c#.

Comment: have you do pagination in your grid?

Comment: It's standard pagination of telerik grid, PageSize="10" and AllowPaging="True" these two properties are set for pagging

Answer (score 0):

You need to use lazy loading, load only those records which you are currently being displayed in the grid, it could be 500 or 10 or 15 depending on your scenario.

The logic should be in the DB to fetch the required number of records. In SQL Server 2012 you can use the OFFSET and FETCH NEXT keywords, in case of older versions you can use ROW_NUMBER.

Comment: Can you provide me some example, it will be more helpfull

Comment: Please check this link (http://www.dotnetbull.com/2013/05/custom-paging-in-aspnet-using-stored.html), the example talks about GridView, but the code should work for Telerik with minor changes.

Comment: but i also want to handle sorting.

Comment: The link provided uses sorting to fetch the records by creationdate, you should change it to suit your fields.

Answer (score 0):

In telerik grid views, you can configure that how many data you want to be shown in the data grid table and which page are you selected!

So you could send your request to the database by **IPagedList**.

For example you want to show 500 data per page and you select page 3 between 100  pages (50000 data in 100 pages that each one contains 500 data) and rapidly the data of row number of 1001 to 1500 will be shown (depends on the sorting condition) in the data table grid.

Please see the below atricle from Microsoft:

[PagedList Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.fabric.query.pagedlist-1?view=azure-dotnet)